# Strange behavior of Julia's lpad function and string interpolation

Tags: julia

The following code surprised me:

```
julia> for person in 1:12
           println("person is $(lpad(2, person))")
       end
person is 2
person is  2
person is   2
person is    2
person is     2
person is      2
person is       2
person is        2
person is         2
person is          2
person is           2
person is            2
```

It seemed totally mysterious until I realized I had entered the arguments to the `lpad` function in reverse order.  That fixed it:

```
julia> for person in 1:12
           println("person is $(lpad(person, 2))")
        end
person is  1
person is  2
person is  3
person is  4
person is  5
person is  6
person is  7
person is  8
person is  9
person is 10
person is 11
person is 12
```

However, there must be something going on that I am not getting about `lpad` and the unexpected output.

Below is the `lpad` function's signature in the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/strings/#Base.lpad):

```
lpad(s, n::Integer, p::Union{AbstractChar,AbstractString}=' ') -> String
```

Any suggestions as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop counter is called "person" for some reason. So it loops from 1 to 12.

From the function docs, the second argument determines the count of left padding of the
printed first argument:

```
lpad(s, n::Integer, p::Union{AbstractChar,AbstractString}=' ') -> String

Stringify s and pad the resulting string on the left with p to make
it n characters (code points) long. If s is already n characters long,
an equal string is returned. Pad with spaces by default.
```

So your loop counter is person and this is also the number of spaces 
printed before the '2' each line of output in the first version.

Comment: Thanks!  I had thought that when I accidentally flipped the order of the arguments I should have gotten an error message.  But now I see the the "Stringify s" comment from the function docs means that my integer `2` just got made into a string, instead of causing an error.  Seems obvious now that you have pointed it out.